# Como faço esta lista que esta na imagem

Tags: html

Bom estou aprendendo html com css para dar entrada futuramente em php porem estou com uma dificuldade não consigo fazer Div class com listas pois ele não aplica a cor etc... a cor esta em outro arquivo de formatação.css preciso de ajuda pls[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acordo com a resposta do Victor, você deve importar o seu arquivo CSS para a sua página HTML. Para mudar o fundo da lista, aqui tem um exemplo:

```html
<html>
<head>
 <style type="text/css">
  li {
   list-style-position: inside;
   text-indent: -1em;
   padding: 10px 2em;
   background-color: #CCCCCC;
  }
  li.azul {
   background-color: #0000FF;
  }
  li.amarelo {
   background-color: #FFFF00;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
<li class="azul">Item 1</li>
<li class="azul">Item 2</li>
<li class="azul">Item 3</li>
<li class="amarelo">Item 4</li>
<li class="amarelo">Item 5</li>
<li class="amarelo">Item 6</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda <3

Answer (score 0):

Que legal que está se aventurando nesta área do desenvolvimento web. O que você está querendo fazer é uma importação de um arquivo **css** para o seu arquivo **html**.

Suponhamos que você criou um projeto chamado *loja* e o representou através de uma pasta nomeada `/loja`. Os seus arquivos HTML e CSS devem estar dentro dessa pasta para melhor organização. Na raiz da pasta existem dois arquivos que podemos chamar de `index.html` representando seu arquivo de marcação HTML e `style.css` representando seu arquivo de estilização CSS.

> Note que os dois arquivos estão na pasta raiz, ou seja, dentro da pasta `loja`.

Para importar uma folha de estilos (*style.css*) é necessário declarar um elemento `link` no escopo do elemento `head`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
<body>    
    <h1>This is a heading</h1>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>    
</body>
</html>
```

---

O [W3C Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp) possui um ótimo conteúdo para aprendizado de HTML e também outras linguagens de interesse.

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda pessoal